# Possible to put records that aren't same length as header records to bad_record directory

Tags: scala, apache-spark, error-handling, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am reading a file into a dataframe like this

```
val df = spark.read
   .option("sep", props.inputSeperator)
   .option("header", "true")
   .option("badRecordsPath", "/mnt/adls/udf_databricks/error")
   .csv(inputLoc)
```

The file is setup like this

```
col_a|col_b|col_c|col_d
1|first|last|
2|this|is|data
3|ok
4|more||stuff
5|||
```

Now, spark will read all of this as acceptable data. However, I want `3|ok` to be marked as a bad record because it's size does not match the header size.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val a = spark.sparkContext.textFile(pathOfYourFile)
val size = a.first.split("\\|").length
a.filter(i => i.split("\\|",-1).size != size).saveAsTextFile("/mnt/adls/udf_databricks/error")
```

Comment: Thanks.. However, the code I provided works and it generates a BadRecord output, just doesn't contain lines with less than wanted size.   So, I would assume that means badRecordsPath option exists? (It generates a timestamped folder inside of `/mnt/adls/udf_databricks/error` along with a part file of the output.  Either way, your solution will be sufficient, thanks.

Comment: which version of spark you are using ? Let me check the source code.

Comment: Version 2.3.1 //

Comment: Thanks for bringing this. I was not aware of that option. One upvote for this.

Comment: No problem, I assume that even though this option exists for csv, you can't modify it in a way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: try giving the specified schema using .schema method in your solution

Comment: Please try changing the nullable parameter to false

Comment: Null is an acceptable value though, its only completely missing records that I want marked, so `a|||` is acceptable, but `a|` is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is supported by databricks implementation of spark.I dont see schema mapping in your code. could you map it and try ?

```
.option("badRecordsPath", "/mnt/adls/udf_databricks/error")
```

Change your code like below,

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("col_a", StringType, true),
    StructField("col_b", StringType, true),
    StructField("col_c", StringType, true),
    StructField("col_d", StringType, true)))

val df = spark.read
   .option("sep", props.inputSeperator)
   .option("header", "true")
   .option("badRecordsPath", "/mnt/adls/udf_databricks/error")
   .schema(customSchema)
   .csv(inputLoc)
```

More detail's you can refer [Datbricks doc on badrecordspath](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html)

Thanks,
Karthick

Comment: Okay, this fixed my issue, however, having to mantain a schema will add some overhead.  The schema is always all string type, based on the header column names.  I do not want to use infer schema because I have hundreds of millions of records, and that will be to costly.  Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Just to add on, I have no knowledge of what the column names are.  All I know is I have a header row in `inputLoc` and that they are all string types.  I would prefer not do 2 read operations, one to get the header line, then one again to read it into a dataframe. @Karthick

Comment: @testacc: You could read the header with plain scala and dynamically create the schema to use as above. It would not add that much overhead if it's a single file.