# Spark row level error handling , how to get error message at row level

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a csv file which i am loading through spark . I want to separate the good and bad records and also want to know each row level error of the bad records .

I am specifying a schema and can capture corrupt_records like this , but how to get the error message for each different corrupt records?

```
  --------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|service_point_number|energy_type|is_enabled|            metadata|testint|     _corrupt_record|
+--------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|            90453512|          E|     false|Address1@420#Addr...|     23|                null|
|            14802348|          G|     false|Address1@420#Addr...|     24|                null|
|                null|       null|      null|                null|   null|99944990,E,12,Add...|
|            78377144|          E|     false|                 123|     26|                null|
|            25506816|          G|     false|Address1@420#Addr...|     27|                null|
|            48789905|          E|      true|Address1@420#Addr...|   null|48789905,E,true,A...|
|            20283032|          E|     false|Address1@420#Addr...|     29|                null|
|            67311231|          G|     false|Address1@420#Addr...|     30|                null|
|            18240558|          G|     false|Address1@420#Addr...|     31|18240558,G,false,...|
|            42631153|          E|     false|Address1@420#Addr...|     32|                null|
+--------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

the spark-csv package integrated in spark from 2.x offers
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html

```
badRecordsPath
```

See an sample for CSV at [Possible to put records that aren't same length as header records to bad_record directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043653/possible-to-put-records-that-arent-same-length-as-header-records-to-bad-record)

Comment: Have tried this already , but couldn't find any file where bad records are written in HDFS .I am using spark version version 2.3.1 .I am using spark version 2.3.1. `val df = spark.read.format("cs").option("header", "true").option("badRecordsPath", "/sampledata/test").schema(schema).csv("/sampledata/test.csv")`

Comment: I tried finding in /sampledata/test  in HDFS @georg

Comment: Did you try to run it in Databricks or open source spark? It might be the case that this feature is only available there. But I am not 100% sure about this.

Comment: I am using spark in EMR and can't see the badRecordsPath option available there .

Answer (score 0):

[badRecordsPath](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html) can work but perhaps the reason you can't find it in the specified path is that the actual execution will not start until an action is triggered. Try using `df.show()` after your code `spark.read...` then look again if the output file is shown now in the path.